# post-redirect? not working in liberator or Preflight response is not successful

Tags: clojure, liberator

I have the following code:

```
defresource handle-sign-in [redirect-uri]
  :available-media-types ["application/json"]
  :allowed-methods [:post]
  :post! (prn "welcome to post")
  :post-redirect? (fn [_] ;;(ring-response
                           {:location redirect-uri}
                           ;;)
                    )
  )
```

When I send the request, I get the errors `Preflight response is not successful` and `XMLHttpRequest cannot load [authorize-uri] due to access control checks.`
When I wrap the redirect location map around ring-response, however, I don't get the errors but neither do I get the redirect in the browser. What am I doing wrong?

-- EDIT --

This is my system.components config.

```
(defn config []
  {:http-port  (Integer. (or (env :port) 5000))
   :middleware [[wrap-defaults api-defaults]
                wrap-with-logger
                wrap-gzip
                ignore-trailing-slash
                [wrap-reload {:dir "../../src"}]
                [wrap-trace :header :ui]
                wrap-params
                wrap-keyword-params
                wrap-cookies
                [wrap-cors #".*"]
                ]})
```

and this is what my new resource looks like:

```
(defresource handle-sign-in [authorize-uri]
  :available-media-types ["application/json"]
  :allowed-methods [:post]
  :post-redirect? true
  :as-response (fn [d ctx]
                 (-> (as-response d ctx) ;; default implementation
                     (assoc-in [:headers "Access-Control-Allow-Origin"] "*")
                     (assoc-in [:headers "Access-Control-Allow-Headers"] "Content-Type")
                     )

                 )
  :location authorize-uri
  )
```

But I still get the "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource." error.

Answer (score 0):

Please read about [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS). You'd need to either implement the `OPTIONS` method in the resource or wrap your handler with appropriate middleware, e.g. [ring-cors](https://github.com/r0man/ring-cors).

Comment: I tried the wrap cors middleware but still get the "access-control-allow-origin isn't present" error. Also, I couldn't find how to implement ```OPTIONS``` in the liberator documentation. How do I do that?

Comment: Also I tried adding the custom headers using as-response (see edit).

Comment: @zengod can you paste the request and response headers somewhere?